# basemap round stereographic plot mapboundary cropped

Tags: matplotlib, projection, matplotlib-basemap

I'm struggling with round stereographic plots using the matplotlib basemap toolkit.
I always get a cropped map boundary at the top, bottom and left, right. The example code:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

m = Basemap(projection='spstere', boundinglat=-60, lon_0=180,
lat_ts=-71, round=True, ellps='WGS84')

m.drawparallels(np.arange(-90.,-60.0, 10.), linewidth=0.1)
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(-180.,181.,45.), linewidth=0.1, latmax=90)
m.drawmapboundary(linewidth=2, color='k')

plt.savefig("test.png",dpi=600, transparent=True)
plt.show()
```

This results in:
[image: cropped map boundary]

I marked the cropped off part with red ellipses (top and left). It doesn't make a difference if I change the "linewidth" parameter.

Is there a workaround for this problem to make the boundary evenly in line width?
Thanks for any help and suggestions in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The circle that defines the map boundary is clipped by the actual axes in use. You may use the `clip_on` option to let it not be clipped.

```
circle = m.drawmapboundary(linewidth=2, color='k')
circle.set_clip_on(False)
```

The example code then look like this

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

m = Basemap(projection='spstere', boundinglat=-60, lon_0=180,
lat_ts=-71, round=True, ellps='WGS84')

m.drawparallels(np.arange(-90.,-60.0, 10.), linewidth=0.1)
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(-180.,181.,45.), linewidth=0.1, latmax=90)
circle = m.drawmapboundary(linewidth=2, color='k')
circle.set_clip_on(False)

plt.savefig("test.png",dpi=600, transparent=True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank your very much. This works fine. But there is one restriction. If the linewidth of drawmapboundary is less than 1, the problem remains.

Comment: What you see when the linewidth is less than 1 is something different. Vertical and horizontal lines are then exactly one pixels thick, while the rest of the circle appears thicker due to antialiasing.

Answer (score 0):

I used `circle.set_clip_on(False)` option, thank you! Now the continents and rivers are plotted on top of the circle boundary, although I tried changing the zorder of the plotting. How could I fix this please?

Here's my code :

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap;
import numpy as np;
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt;

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(9,7));
m = Basemap(projection='npstere', boundinglat=70, lon_0=0, resolution='l', round=True);
m.fillcontinents(color='silver');
m.drawcoastlines(color='w');
m.drawparallels(np.arange(70.,81.,10.),labels=[False,False,False,False], fontsize=ft);
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(0.,360.,90.),labels=[True,True,True,True], fontsize=ft);
circle = m.drawmapboundary(linewidth=3, color='k');
circle.set_clip_on(False);
plt.show()
```

And here is what it shows :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dK4Zo.png)